# Silex APP on subfolder

Tags: php, silex

I want to host a Silex application on *localhost/mytestfolder/*, but as I noticed, every time I route an URL I have to do

```
$app->get('mytestfolder/myRoute' ...
```

Is there a way I can configure the router so I just do

```
$app->get('myRoute' ...
```

Comment: Which webserver are you using? If apache, have you set the RewriteBase directive as outlined? http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to put web directory on your RewriteBase

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /lolcollege/web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ app/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```